# [Rails]jQuery: Syntax error, unrecognized expression

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, syntax-error, sizzle

I've a problem with my Rails 3 app: I've a script in my view to display a progress bar for an upload (the upload process works):

```
<h1>Ajouter des images:</h1>

<%= form_for [:admin, :gallery,  @painting], html: { multipart: true} do |f| %>

  <%= f.hidden_field :gallery_id %>

  <%= f.label :image, "Upload paintings:" %>

  <%= f.file_field :image, multiple: true, name: "painting[image]" %>

<% end %>

<script id="template-upload" type="text/x-tmpl">
  <div class="upload">
    {%=o.name%}
    <div class="progress"><div class="bar" style="width: 0%"></div></div>
  </div>
</script>
```

But when i try to upload a file, i got this error:

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: <div class="upload">
  Argentina.gif
  <div class="progress"><div class="bar" style="width: 0%"></div></div>
</div>
```

Coming form the jquery.js file:

```
Sizzle.error = function( msg ) {
    throw new Error( "Syntax error, unrecognized expression: " + msg );
```

I really don't know how to fix it, i've already sought a lot !
Thanks for your help !

Comment: So where is jQuery in your code?

Comment: In ruby on rails, the jquery lib is included trough the "gems", so i don't have a direct access to the file. thanks for your answer !

Comment: No solution ? I get exactly the same error with the other HTML tags !

Comment: You should provide the related JS codes, your question is at is doesn't help people to help you. You have just posted the error, not the culprit.

Comment: The script is in the page in my post.

Comment: <script id="template-upload" type="text/x-tmpl">
  <div class="upload">
    {%=o.name%}
    <div class="progress"><div class="bar" style="width: 0%"></div></div>
  </div>
</script>

Comment: Yes, you can only write JavaScript within script tags not HTML markup.

Comment: Sizzle permits me to do it ;)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is happening because of the identation inside your template tag. Check it out: [jquery-htmlstring-versus-jquery-selectorstring](http://stage.jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#jquery-htmlstring-versus-jquery-selectorstring)

You can avoid it by using [`$.parseHTML()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseHTML/):

```
data.context = $($.parseHTML(tmpl("template-upload", file))[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

jquery-file-upload has a compatibility problem in ruby 1.9.x. There was a recent fix https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/pull/2031

Others were having the same problem (myself included) https://github.com/waynehoover/s3_direct_upload/issues/47.

Try updating your gem with `bundle update jquery-fileupload-rails`. (I assume you're using that gem.)

Comment: adding trim makes it compatable

Answer (score 0):

Remove Jquery function **$( )** when you use template. This is compatible with Jquery 1.9.1. You should process template like bellow

```
tmpl("template-upload", {file: file, icon: icon_name[type]})
```

instead of

```
$(tmpl("template-upload", {file: file, icon: icon_name[type]}))
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the latest version of jquery, add `tril` to it should do the trick

```
$(tmpl("template-upload", {file: file, icon: icon_name[type]}).trim())
```